# Error : Field mapping for CSV in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, ftp, ftp-client

I have a function that downloads CSV file by invoking attributes from FTP server , i used field mapping in order to map the attributes accordingly .

How can possibly resolve this error

```
def download_csv(page_id = fetch_grid_ids.first, mapping: mapping, csv_options: csv_options)
      results = fetch_grid(page_id)
      records = results['response']['data']
      output = []
      record_count = records.size

      if mapping
        headers = mapping.values
        download_headers = mapping.keys
      elsif @config[:output_file_headers]
        headers = @config[:output_file_headers]
        download_headers = headers
      else
        headers = data.first.keys
        headers.shift
        download_headers = headers
      end

      download_headers = download_headers.map(&:to_s)

      output << CSV.generate_line(headers, csv_options)

      records.each_with_index do |r, i|
        row = []

        download_headers.each do |h|
          row << r[h] rescue nil
        end

        logger.info "PriceFx::Client.download: #{i + 1}/#{record_count} :: #{row.size}"
        output << CSV.generate_line(row, csv_options)
      end

      filename = "#{Rails.configuration.tmp_dir}/#{@config[:output_file]}_#{page_id}.csv"
      File.open(filename, 'wb') {|f| f.puts output }

      return filename
    end
```

following is the error that i am getting

```
client.rb:224: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
... fetch_grid_ids.first, mapping: mapping, csv_options: csv_op...
...                               ^
client.rb:452: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

any clues how can i resolve this

Answer (score 0):

In method definition, double-splatted params might have default values, and you are trying to supply default values with non-existing local variables:

```
#                                        ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ ???
download_csv(page_id = default, mapping: mapping, ...)
```

One might put `nil` there, or any applicable *and defined* default value, e.g.:

```
DEFAULT_MAPPING = ...
download_csv(page_id = default, mapping: DEFAULT_MAPPING, ...)
```